# Reference with hic, is and ille

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-choice, syntax, pronouns, demonstrative-pronoun

Consider this example:

> *Ecce Marcus et Gaius. Hic canit, ille auscultat.*
>   Here are Marcus and Gaius. The latter sings, the former listens.

When there are two or more things one could refer to, *hic* often means "the latter".
The first of two can then be referred to with *ille* or *is* unless I am mistaken, but *ille* seems to be at least more common.
I am not sure whether *is* is possible and when so, but I would like to figure that out.

Is there a difference between *is* and *ille* in references like this?
That is, can I use *is* instead of *ille* here, or would it mean something else?
In case of two (here Marcus and Gaius), would *is* refer to Marcus or Gaius, our would it not refer clearly to either one?

I think the usual latter/former pair is *hic/ille*, but I am unsure of the role of *is*.
I am not sure it has any role like this at all.

This came up when I wrote an answer to [a pronoun ambiguity question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2118/79) yesterday.

Comment: [Linking my previous answer](http://latin.stackexchange.com/a/534/78). I'm refraining from voting for the time being, but I do think it should be closed as redundant unless you were to demonstrate your speculation, i.e. what gives you the impression that you can substitute *is* for *ille* in this construction.

Comment: I'm with @C.M.Weimer: *hic/ille* is a pretty established construction, and I think it might be better to ask "is it possible?" rather than "what's the difference?"

Comment: From the intro of *Captivi*, *is* is used immediately after *hic* with the same antecedent and no kind of opposition: "senex qui hic habitat Hegio est **huius** pater. / sed **is** quo pacto serviat suo sibi patri, / id ego hic apud vos proloquar"

Comment: @brianpck, at the time of asking I was unsure whether the correct pair of *hic* is *ille* or *is*. I reformulated the question somewhat, and I hope it is better. (In fact, C. M. Weimer's answer to the other question lists a third pronoun to refer further back than *hic* and *ille*, and I am tempted to make a separate question about that. We already have an answer, but I would much like to have a specific question about just that extension.)

Comment: I was searching this site to find the difference between "is" and "ille" when meaning "he", I stumbled upon your question by chance, but its title doesn't help. Could you reformulate the title to show the "is/ille/hic" difference for "he" (connotations), so we could find it when wondering this same question?

Comment: @Quidam This question is not quite about *is/ille/hic* as "he", but about the reference to a number of previously mentioned things which may or may not be people. A separate question "What is the difference between is, ille, and hic as 'he'?" would be nice to have. It could of course link here. This question is only about multiple references, but most uses of these pronouns only have a single reference and the game is different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be able to find *noun<sub>a</sub>*...*noun<sub>b</sub>*, *is<sub>b</sub>*...*sed ille<sub>a</sub>*, but that's an unusual pairing, and you'd probably want to read it more literally, i.e. "he did X, but the former/latter did Y."

The most common pairing is *noun<sub>a</sub>*...*noun<sub>b</sub>*, *hic<sub>b</sub>*...*ille<sub>a</sub>*. Allen & Greenough §297 have this to say about *is* in this usage:

> **Is** is a weaker demonstrative than the others and is especially common as a personal pronoun. It does not denote any special object, but refers to one just mentioned, or to be afterwards explained by a relative. **Often it is merely a correlative to the relative *qui***. [Emphasis mine.]

They give an example of this usage (from Att. ii. 1. 1):

> *venit mihi obviam tuus puer, is mihi litteras abs te reddidit* | your boy met me, [and] he delivered to me a letter from you.

As you can see, this isn't quite the same usage or strength. A glance through Gildersleeve and Lodge doesn't even hint that *is* could be used in place of *hic*/*ille*. Your best bet is to stick with the standard construction unless you're familiar enough with *why* there might be an exception (and my gut is telling me it's rather colloquial).

Comment: I still have troubles to summarize the difference between "is" and "ille" to mean "he". Can you be less implicit with the "as you can see". It's not so obvious for a beginner like me.

Comment: @Quidam This question doesn't directly look at that specific difference. Which part are you confused on, and I can clear that up.